# how to get facebook email id from Nodge/yii2-eauth

Tags: composer-php, yii2, yii-extensions, yii-components, yii2-user

Am trying to integrate Yii2 EAuth for facebook login integration.

I made configaration * in model am using below code

```
 public static function findIdentity($id) {
        if (Yii::$app->getSession()->has('user-'.$id)) {
            return new self(Yii::$app->getSession()->get('user-'.$id));
        }
        else {
            return isset(self::$users[$id]) ? new self(self::$users[$id]) : null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param \nodge\eauth\ServiceBase $service
     * @return User
     * @throws ErrorException
     */
    public function findByEAuth($service) {

        if (!$service->getIsAuthenticated()) {
            throw new ErrorException('EAuth user should be authenticated before creating identity.');
        }

        $id = $service->getServiceName().'-'.$service->getId();

        // echo $id;exit;

        print_r($service->getAttribute('email'));

        echo '<pre>';

        print_r($service->getAttributes());
        exit;



        $attributes = array(
            'id' => $id,
            'username' => $service->getAttribute('name'),
            'authKey' => md5(@$id),
            'profile' => $service->getAttributes(),
        );


        $attributes['profile']['service'] = $service->getServiceName();
        Yii::$app->getSession()->set('user-'.$id, $attributes);
        return new self($attributes);
    }
```

i want email , pls can any one help me to get facebook email id...thanks in advance......

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the email of the user from facebook after changing the few setting in vendor\nodge\yii2-eauth\src\services\FacebookOAuth2Service.php.

Edit FacebookOAuth2Service.php

Override `protected $scopes = array(self::SCOPE_EMAIL);`

And modify the fetchAttributes() functions. It should look like this:

```
    protected function fetchAttributes()
    {
            $info = $this->makeSignedRequest('me');

            $this->attributes['id'] = $info['id'];
            $this->attributes['name'] = $info['name'];
            $this->attributes['url'] = $info['link'];
            $this->attributes['email'] = $info['email'];

            return true;
   }
```

Try and see it it works for you.